# Groups api return empty string

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

Please help me get group list from facebook api.

When I use this code:

```
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$groups = $facebook->api('/me/groups','GET', array('access_token' => $token));
```

It returns empty array.

Or if I cut the access token off it still doesn't work.

But when I call the graph api with:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/groups?access_token=....

It returns all of groups, and when I use:

```
$groups = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/groups?access_token='.$token);
```

It returns empty json too.

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to add `user_groups` permission in order to get the result.

When you facebook login:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
          ...
      } else {
        ....
      }
  }, {scope: 'user_groups'});
```

**EDIT:**

With using Facebook PHP SDK:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_groups'));
```

Comment: Thanks but
If I use PHP SDK How to use login?
I have a loginUrl via getLoginUrl()
but how to request a permission with login?